# jQuery Tabs into iframe (Joomla) resize height

Tags: jquery, iframe, joomla, jquery-ui-tabs

i have this tabs in an file that i have included with an iframe into my joomla 3x site.

```html
<div id="tabs">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#tabs-1">Nunc tincidunt</a></li>
    <li><a href="#tabs-2">Proin dolor</a></li>
    <li><a href="#tabs-3">Aenean lacinia</a></li>
  </ul>
  <div id="tabs-1">
 
  </div>
  <div id="tabs-2">
 
  </div>
  <div id="tabs-3">
    
  </div>
</div>
```

So one of the tabs has a bigger height than the other, and if i run the file with the tabs into my browser,it will work normaly resizing the tabs. But I want to embed it into an inframe in Joomla, does anybody know how to automaticly resize my iframe to the height of the tab knowing that to resize the I need to resize the content div so the iframe will fit?
Thank you very much.And sorry for my bad english

Comment: Have you tried adding `iframe { height:auto; }` in your CSS ?

Comment: yes, and it doesn't change anything, i think it's a javascript or a jquery

Comment: Unfortunately without seeing a JSFiddle or a preview of the live site, we can't really help debug that much